# Jquery hide show list

Tags: jquery

Having few issues with a jquery hide show item.

Got a list of images, want to show the first one but hide the rest and when the user clicks next the current one is hidden and then the next list item is shown.

Been banging head against wall for a while, and there is probably a very easy solution but for some reason I am unable to see it. Would be grateful of any advice.

```
    $(function() {
    $('#feat>li:gt(0)').hide();
    var $links = $('#feat>li');
    var $item  = $('#feat>li');

    $links.click(function() {
        var $par = $(this);
        $par.slideUp(700, function() {
            var index = $links.index( $par.get(0) )
            $item.eq( index ).slideDown(700);
        }); 
    });
});

    <div id="feature">
    <ul id="feat">
        <li><img src="images/sample.png" /><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        <li><img src="images/sample2.jpg" /><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        <li><img src="images/sample.png" /><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested, should work:

```
$('#feat li').hide().eq(0).show();

// Option 1: Simultaneous slidings:
$('#feat a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp().next().slideDown();
});

// Option 2: Hide first, then show:
$('#feat a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp(700, function() {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    })
});
```

Comment: what would you do to stop the user clicking last item and hiding image?

Comment: I have changed it to work on clicking image, so how would you have it so when user reached last image and user starts clicking again it goes back through them to start.

Comment: Don't bind the click handler to the last image, e.g. `$('#feat img').not(':last').click(...)`